# CoreBluetooth crashes when detecting some devices on iPad

Tags: ios

I have been building an app using Xcode and Swift. The app uses `CoreBluetooth` to connect with a Bluetooth Low Energy device.

The app scans for devices and lists them in a `tableView`. If a device is found that matches the correct service ID, it gets added to the device array, and therefore to the `tableView`, however, I've written the app so that if a device is detected that does not have the correct service ID in the advertisement data, it is not added to the `tableView`. This therefore means that a device such as this isn't one that I want to connect to.

I've been testing the app on an iPhone 6, and it detects the correct device and adds it to the array and `tableView`, and any other device that is the wrong device doesn't get added.

However, I seem to be having problems with the app on an iPad 3. When running the app, it detects the correct device and adds it to the array and `tableView`. However, when it detects a device that doesn't have the service ID available, it crashes, instead of not adding it to the list.

The code I've used is below:

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
    if discoveredDeviceArray.contains(peripheral.name!) {
        print("INFORMATION: Detected device \(peripheral.name!) but it already exists in the list. Skipping for now...")
    } else {
        if peripheral.name != nil { //Check to ensure that a nil device hasn't been detected - this otherwise will cause the app to crash.
                if advertisementData.description.contains("FFB0"){
                    print("INFORMATION: Discovered \(peripheral.name!) and it was added to the list of detected test devices.")
                    discoveredDeviceArray.append(peripheral.name!)
                    discoveredDeviceArrayInfo.append(peripheral)
                    self.bluetoothTableView.reloadData()
                } else {
                    print("WARNING: The device \(peripheral.name!) was discovered but not added to the list since it is not a test device.")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, it crashes on the iPad when it detects my Macbook's bluetooth signal. The iPhone detects this fine and correctly doesn't add it to the list.

The app crashes on the line

```
self.bluetoothTableView.reloadData()
```

with the error:

`Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)`

I think that this is something to do with not unwrapping optionals for one of the `centralManager` parameters, specifically `advertisementData`, but it surprises me since it only seems to be occurring on the iPad.

Is there any code here that you can see that is obviously wrong and needs to be corrected?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I had experienced something similar in past and in my case by the time my table view was being reloaded, the model containing devices was being changed. I then had to disconnect model update from the reload i.e. ensuring that while table is being loaded model is not affected; you can use a `copy` of it. Please see if your case does fall in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It's really appreciated! What do you mean by a `copy` of it?

Comment: I meant calling 'copy' function on your model before using it for update. Basically, it creates another copy in memory ensuring table is always consuming a stable model. Unfortunately, Wi-Fi is down at my place otherwise I could share some code.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I'm just not sure how to implement it within the code. When you get your Wi-Fi working, can you share some for me? That would be a great help to me!